# Calculate the winding number of a triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

My question is about calculating the winding number of a triangle, i.e. 
$$
Ind_\gamma(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_\gamma\frac{1}{w-z}dw,
$$
where $\gamma$ is the path given by the border of a triangle $\Delta \subset \mathbb C$.

---

What I have done so far is calculating the value of the function outside of the triangle, and that is $Ind_\gamma(z) = 0 \quad \forall z \notin\Delta$ $\;$, but I don't know how to calculate it inside $\Delta$, intuitively I guess that its value is $Ind_\gamma(z) = 1 \quad \forall z \in\Delta.$

Comment: " intuitively I guess that.." basing on what theorem? What definition of the winding number do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of "calculation" you are looking for. But this follows essentially from Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: The intuitive idea of the function $Ind_\gamma(z) = \int_\gamma\frac{1}{w-z}dw$ is that it tells the number of counterclockwise turns that the path makes around the point z. [Link of the Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number). @Jack

Comment: The winding number in *complex functions* is defined by the integral you wrote **times** $\;\frac1{2\pi i}\;$ ...

Comment: You are right, I'll edit it. @DonAntonio

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), with $\;f(z)=1\;$ , and get

$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_\Delta\frac1{w-z}dw=f(z)=1$$

and we're done.

Another way is trying to parametrize the triangle's perimeter curve, say: take the triangle whose vertices are $\;(0,0),\,(0,1),\,(1,0)\;$, then the horizontal side is parametrized by $\;r(t)=t(1,0)+(1-t)(0,0)=(t,0),\,0\le t\;$ , and etc.